# ObjectMapper how map Dictionary of [String:CustomObject] With Index as CustomObject Property

Tags: ios, json, swift, objectmapper

I started to use ObjectMapper this week and I'm trying to map a JSON into 2 CustomClasses but I don't known if ObjectMapper has some function to do what I want. First CustomClass has a property of type: [String:CustomClass2] where the index of this Dictionary should be property ID of second CustomObject.

JSON Used:

```
{ 
  "types": [
   { 
    "id": "mk8QPMSo2xvtSoP0cBUD",
    "name": "type 1",
    "img": "type_1",
    "showCategories": false,
    "modalityHint": [
      "K7VqeFkRQNXoh2OBxgIf"
    ],
    "categories": [
      "mP3MqbJrO5Da1dVAPRvk",
      "SlNezp2m3PECnTyqQMUV"
    ]
   }
  ]
}
```

Classes Used:

```
class MyClass: Mappable {
    var types:[String:MyClass2] = [String:MyClass2]() //Index should be ID property of MyClass2 Object
    required init?(map:Map) {
        guard map.JSON["types"] != nil else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        types <- map["types"]
    }
}
class MyClass2: Mappable {
    private var id: String!
    private var name: String!
    private var img: String!
    private var showCategories: Bool!
    private var modalityHint: [String]?
    private var categories: [String]?
    required init?(map: Map) { }
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        id <- map["id"]
        name <- map["name"]
        img <- map["img"]
        showCategories <- map["showCategories"]
        modalityHint <- map["modalityHint"]
        categories <- map["categories"]
}
```

Comment: i think types shouldn't be `[String:Class2]`, just `[Class2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JSON the `types` key is an `array` not a `Dictionary`.

Change:

```
var types:[String:MyClass2] = [String:MyClass2]()
```

To:

```
var types:[Class2] = []
```

Like this:

```
class MyClass: Mappable {
    private var arrayTypes = [MyClass2] {
        didSet{
            var mapTypes = [String:MyClass2]?
            for obj in arrayTypes {
                mapTypes[obj.id] = obj
            }

            types = mapTypes
        }
    }

    var types:[String:MyClass2] = [String:MyClass2]()
    required init?(map:Map) {
        guard map.JSON["types"] != nil else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        arrayTypes <- map["types"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, my json structure is different from my Class structure but is there a way to make this transform using ObjectMapper functions?

Comment: So you want to map it into a Dictionary using the id value as the key in the Dictionary?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Do you know if it's possible?

Comment: Not directly you will have to map the response to an array in a seperate private variable and then on the didSet of that property loop over it and map each id to MyClass2 and set it as types.